# How to get data from multiple json object

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I know how to get data from normal json data but recently I came across this new question where the json looks like

```
 "product_1": {
"productId": "product_1",
"customerId": "customer_1",
"brandCode": "BRD0050",
"brandName": "ABC.ST.",
"productCode": 700251,
"productDesc": "ABC  AB 50gm Sac",
"mrp": 15,
"expiry": 1608461977
},
"product_2": {
"productId": "product_2",
"customerId": "customer_1",
"brandCode": "BRD0050",
"brandName": "ABC.ST.",
"productCode": 700251,
"productDesc": "ABC  AB 50gm Sac",
"mrp": 17,
"expiry": 1608462037
},
"product_3": {
"productId": "product_3",
"customerId": "customer_1",
"brandCode": "BRD0050",
"brandName": "ABC.ST.",
"productCode": 700251,
"productDesc": "ABC  AB 50gm Sac",
"mrp": 17,
"expiry": 1608461978
}...
```

goes till product_150

so I looked for quite some time in google but not able to get any value 
this is what i have tried

```
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        //    JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("product_" + j);
        Iterator<String> keyIterator = obj.keys();
        Log.e("Details",""+obj.keys().hasNext());
        while(keyIterator.hasNext()) {
            String productKey = keyIterator.next();

            JSONObject jo_inside = obj.getJSONObject(productKey);


            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> formList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> m_li;

           /* for (int i = 0; i < jo_inside.length(); i++) {
                Log.e("Details",""+jo_inside.length());
                Log.e("Details-->", jo_inside.getString("productId"));
                String formula_value = jo_inside.getString("formule");
                String url_value = jo_inside.getString("url");

                //Add your values in your `ArrayList` as below:
                m_li = new HashMap<String, String>();
                m_li.put("formule", formula_value);
                m_li.put("url", url_value);

                formList.add(m_li);


            }

            */
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

where I am getting data from the asset file. I have only tried to get data in **Log** any clue what I am doing wrong or what my approach should be? currently, I made a for loop till 150 and getting the data like that.

Comment: instead of parsing your json with iterate that json string, you can simply use `GSON` or another libs for getting better result, take look at this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gson/index.htm

Comment: I have no issue with the any of the method the problem is with the json data its like product_1 ...product_150 @javadroid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that `obj.getJSONArray` is not returning anything because the JSON is not notated as an array.  Remove your outer `for` loop, then use `obj.keys()` which should give you an array of keys at the top level of your json object, that based on your provided sample would be ["product_1", "product_2", "product_3"], then you can loop through that array to get each production object, for example;

```
Iterator<String> keyIterator = obj.keys();
while(keyIterator.hasNext()) 
{
    String productKey = keyIterator.next();
    JSONObject jo_inside = obj.getJSONObject(productKey);

    ... rest of your inner for loop here ...
}
```

Comment: how you can get the size from obj.size() its not array or list?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I edited my answer to use an iterator instead, but the point it is, your JSON doesn't have any array in it, so you need to grab the list of Keys at the top level, and grab the object for each top level key to get your data.

Comment: sir what i tried to do is to generate the keys but i guess i was wrong there

Comment: You might have been able to achieve it by generating the keys yourself, if you assume that the keys are always and forever going to be in the format of "product_" + [some number], but for each of those keys, you'd still want to skip right to calling `obj.getJSONObject(somekey)`, because there is no array in your JSON to retrieve by calling `getJSONArray`.

Comment: ya so this was my mistake got it, I will check it and let you know

Comment: i am getting only the first item that is product_1 and not the rest

Comment: can you check the value returned by obj.keys() to see what it is returning, before the `while` loop starts?

Comment: sir it is not going to the next

Comment: Is there an exception occuring somewhere inside the loop?  That would stop it from going to the next iteration.  Maybe try wrapping everything inside the `while` loop inside a try..catch to make sure an inner exception doesn't break the loop?

Comment: sir it is already in a try catch if there was some error i may have got that

Comment: sir i have updated the getdata method hope this may help

Comment: no, do it inside the loop -- if is outside the loop, the first exception will break out of the loop -- something like `while (thingIsTrue) { try { dosomestuffhere(); somemorestuffhere(); } catch(e) { handleErrorInSomeWay() } }